# Floating image after text in table cell

Tags: html, css

How to position the image just behind the text in a table cell?
It is necessary that the image is visible if the text is very long. If the text is short, the image should go right after him.

It is also necessary to support Internet Explorer 8.

**HTML**:

```
<table class="table">
<colgroup>
    <col width="200px">
    <col width="100px">
    <col width="100px">
    <col width="100px">
</colgroup>
 <tr class="table-row">
    <td class="table-cell">
        <div class="table-cell-table">
            <div class="table-cell-text">line 0 cell 1 text</div>
            <div class="table-cell-icon"></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="table-cell">line 0 cell 2</td>
    <td class="table-cell">line 0 cell 3</td>
    <td class="table-cell">line 0 cell 4</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-row">
    <td class="table-cell">
        <div class="table-cell-table">
            <div class="table-cell-text">line 1 cell 1 long text</div>
            <div class="table-cell-icon"></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="table-cell">line 1 cell 2</td>
    <td class="table-cell">line 1 cell 3</td>
    <td class="table-cell">line 1 cell 4</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-row">
    <td class="table-cell">
        <div class="table-cell-table">
            <div class="table-cell-text">line 2 cell 1 very very long text</div>
            <div class="table-cell-icon"></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="table-cell">line 2 cell 2</td>
    <td class="table-cell">line 2 cell 3</td>
    <td class="table-cell">line 2 cell 4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.table {
table-layout: fixed;
width: 500px;
}
.table-cell {
border: 1px solid black;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
}
.table-cell-text {
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
display: inline-block;
}
.table-cell-icon {
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAEFkb2JlIEltYWdlUmVhZHlxyWU8AAAAzklEQVQ4T9XTMQ5EUBQF0DezJr09ieQTO5BYACXRWIKEJShpJRqdDZA3ftwhfx6TyUw1p3Fvc8XHjVf0gzuuX/toYFkWJGkfiOOYrp5mGAbKsgzthT6DJ9/3kaQ0TXkcR7SDMdD3PRdFgSYppZAOxoCWJAlP04RmmueZoyhC24gBLQgCJKmua26aBo359C1YlkVt26KZbNumqqrQVhjadV3HeZ6jSa7rIm2MAf3sYRiiSY7jIB2MAc/zkKSrc9kH3t25LMvTb0D7k5/pGtEDUrgBFbhxrJoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
display: table-cell;
}
.table-cell-table {
display: table;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
} 
.table-cell-table .table-cell-text,
.table-cell-table .table-cell-icon {
display: table-cell;
}
```

Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vpwyddu8/)

What I want is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the width of the elements is not dynamic then you can just set the width of the first column to the width you need (e.g. `col width="250px";`). Change the `display` on `.table-cell-text` and `.table-cell-icon` to `display: inline-block` instead of `table-cell`. I've updated your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vpwyddu8/1/

You can also try setting `float: left` on `.table-cell-text` and `.table-cell-icon` and take out the `display: table-cell` property out of them. This produces a slightly different effect.